# CKEDITOR : Remove selection and set cursor position at the end of selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am facing some selection related issued in CKEDITOR.

**MY GOAL** :

*Remove Selection*

*Set cursor position at the end of the selection*

**MY CODE** :

```
editor.getSelection().removeAllranges();  //Works Fine remove selection

//Try to focus on editor
editor.focus();  // Not Working
```

How can I solve the Problem Guys?

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will get the last range in your current selection, create a range starting and ending at the end position of the last range in your current selection, and select that range.

```
var oldRanges = editor.getSelection().getRanges();
var oldRange = oldRanges[oldRanges.length - 1];
var newRange = editor.createRange();

newRange.setStart(oldRange.endContainer, oldRange.endOffset);
newRange.setEnd(oldRange.endContainer, oldRange.endOffset);

editor.getSelection().selectRanges([ newRange ]);
```

Comment: endContainer of undefined